# Kafka Connect can't find connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use the Kafka Connect Elasticsearch connector, and am unsuccessful. It is crashing with the following error:

```
[2018-11-21 14:48:29,096] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:108)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector , available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='1.0.1', encodedVersion=1.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
```

I've got a build for the plugin unzipped in a kafka subfolder, and have the following line in connect-standalone.properties:

```
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.0.1/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/elasticsearch
```

I can see the various connectors inside that folder, but Kafka Connect does not load them; but it does load the standard connectors, like this:

```
[2018-11-21 14:56:28,258] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:136)
[2018-11-21 14:56:28,259] INFO Added aliases 'FileStreamSinkConnector' and 'FileStreamSink' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:335)
[2018-11-21 14:56:28,260] INFO Added aliases 'FileStreamSourceConnector' and 'FileStreamSource' to plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:335)
```

How can I properly register the connectors?

Answer (score 7):

I ran jdbc connector yesterday manually on kafka in docker without confluent platform etc just to learn how those things works underneath. I did not have to build jar on my side or anyhing like this. Hopefully it will be relevant for you - what I did is ( I will skip docker parts howto mount dir with connector etc ):

- download connector from https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/, unpack zip
- put contents of zip to directory in path configured in properties file ( shown below in 3rd point ) -

  ```
  plugin.path=/plugins
  ```

  so tree looks something like this:

  ```
  /plugins/
  └── jdbcconnector
      └──assets
      └──doc
      └──etc
      └──lib
  ```

  Note the *lib* dir where are the dependencies are, one of them is *kafka-connect-jdbc-5.0.0.jar*
- Now you can try to run connector

  ```
  ./connect-standalone.sh connect-standalone.properties jdbc-connector-config.properties
  ```

  connect-standalone.properties are common properties needed for kafka-connect, in my case:

  ```
  bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
  key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  key.converter.schemas.enable=true
  value.converter.schemas.enable=true
  offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
  offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
  plugin.path=/plugins
  rest.port=8086
  rest.host.name=127.0.0.1
  ```

  jdbc-connector-config.properties is more involving, as it's just configuration for this particular connector, you need to dig into connector docs - for jdbc source it is https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html

Comment: For the JDBC Connect, I've noticed drivers can even be placed in a subfolder of that. E.g lib/drivers

Comment: I keep getting "No such file or directory" when I try to execute plugin.path, any idea why? I am totally new into this

Answer (score 4):

The compiled JAR needs to be available to Kafka Connect. You have a few options here:

1. Use Confluent Platform, which includes the Elasticsearch (and others) pre-built: https://www.confluent.io/download/. There's zip, rpm/deb, Docker images etc available.
2. Build the JAR yourself. This typically involves:

   ```
   cd kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.0.1
   mvn clean package
   ```

   Then take the resulting `kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar` JAR and put it in a path as configured in Kafka Connect with `plugin.path`.

You can find more info on using Kafka Connect here:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and wrote the above blog posts.*

Comment: Building it myself results in this: ```[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.confluent:kafka-connect-elasticsearch:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact io.confluent:common:pom:5.0.1 from/to confluent (${confluent.maven.repo}): ```

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ that's a good reason to use the pre-built version in Confluent Platform ;) It's open source, it's free to use. If you really don't want to, you can d/l it and simply extract the JAR and deploy it in your existing installation.

Comment: OK, I've saved the pre-built version in ```/var/confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.0.0/```. In my config, I have this line: ```plugin.path=/var/silverbolt/confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.0.0/
```. I'm still getting the same error about no matching connector class.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin path must load JAR files, containing compiled code, not raw Java classes of the source code (`src/main/java`).

It also needs to be the *parent directory of other directories* which are containing those plug-ins.

```
plugin.path=/opt/kafka-connect/plugins/
```

Where

```
$ ls - lR /opt/kafka-connect/plugins/
kafka-connect-elasticsearch-x.y.z/
    file1.jar
    file2.jar 
    etc
```

Ref - [Manually installing Community Connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/community.html)

The Kafka Connect startup scripts in the Confluent Platform automatically (used to?) read all folders that match `share/java/kafka-connect-*`, too, so that's one way to go. At least, it will continue doing so, if you include the path to the `share/java` folder of the Confluent package installation in the plugin path as well

If you are not very familiar with Maven, or even if you are, then you actually cannot just clone the Elasticsearch connector repo and [build the master branch; it has prerequisites](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/wiki/FAQ) of first Kafka, then the common Confluent repo first. Otherwise, you must checkout a Git tag like `5.0.1-post` that matches a Confluent release.

An even simpler option would be to [grab the package using Confluent Hub CLI](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/)

And if none of that works, just downloading the Confluent Platform and using the Kafka Connect scripts would be the most easiest. This does not imply you need to use the Kafka or Zookeeper configurations from that

Comment: I built the JAR successfully, moved it into the a folder under /plugins/, added the path to the config, and am still getting the same "failed to find any class" error.

Comment: I believe the Elastic connector actually makes a `tar.gz` file that you need to extract. It doesn't create just one JAR with all the needed classes

Comment: I'm looking at the ```target``` folder, and it created a ```kafka-connect-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar``` file. No ```tar.gz``` that I can see.

Comment: For me, adding a comma at the end solved the issue `plugin.path=/opt/bitnami/kafka/connectors,`. Without the comma, kafka keep complaining failed to find the class.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked once I put the jars in a subdirectory of the folder that the plugin.path points to.

plugin.path=connectors

```
connectors/
   plugins/
      kafka-connect-twitter-0.2.26.jar
      .... <the rest of the jars>
```

Comment: write a readable code please