# Kafka cannot find connector plugins even after configuring plugin.path in worker.properties

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to configure sqlserver debezium connecter in kafka on windows, for that i have downloaded the connector from [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.debezium/debezium-connector-sqlserver/1.0.2.Final/jar) and setup kafka at `C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0` location

created a folder named plugins inside it `C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\plugins` and copied the downloaded jar into the plugins folder.

after that created worker.properties and sqlserverconnector.properties files in config folder with below configuration

**worker.properties config**

```
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets 
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092 
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
#rest.port=10082
#rest.host.name=localhost
#rest.advertised.port=10082
#rest.advertised.host.name=<hostname> 
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false 
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false 
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter 
plugin.path=c:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\plugins
#If kafka is TLS authenticated, uncomment below lines.
#security.protocol=SSL 
#ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
#producer.security.protocol=SSL
#producer.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

**sqlserverconnector.properties**

```
name=sql-server-connection
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=1433
database.user=sa
database.password=Passw0rd
database.dbname=CDCTestDB
#database.server.name=<Assign any name>
#table.whitelist=<schema_name.table_name>
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=test
#If kafka is TLS authenticated, uncomment below lines.
#database.history.producer.security.protocol=SSL
#database.history.producer.ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

also configured connect.standalone plugin.path property to the folder.

when I try to run the connector using the below command

> C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\bin\windows>connect-standalone
>   ../../config/worker.properties
>   ../../config/sqlserverconnector.properties

i am getting the below message

```
 Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
```

[complete error details in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMYHG.png)

if i try to run connect-standalone.sh using below command a new command prompt window is coming and nothing happens, it closes after sometime.

> C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\bin>connect-standalone.sh
>   ../config/worker.properties ../config/sqlserverconnector.properties

can any one help me finding what might be the issue and configure correctly..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53430662

Comment: i tried the options in the link now my plugin directory looks like C:\kafka_2.11-2.4.0\plugins\sqlserverconnectordirect, getting the same error

Comment: @MaheshGupta did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 0):

You must not place the Debezium connector JARs into plugins.dir but to a sub-directory of this dir. So if the plugins.dir is c:\connect then you should have c:\connect\debezium-connector-sqlserver

Comment: Even with this correct configuration, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the plugin path as follows.

```
plugin.path=/c/kafka_2.11-2.4.0/plugins
```

This ran bash needs a different syntax, this one worked for me when running in bash

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the jar files of the Debezium SQL server connector inside a plugins/debezium-connector-sqlserver folder. not directly in the Plugins folder.

```
C:\kafka\plugins\debezium-connector-sqlserver
```

and set the **plugin.path** path like this:

```
plugin.path=C:/kafka/plugins
```